# Call to `[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] recentDocumentURLs]` hangs

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdocumentcontroller

I have an app that routinely calls `[[NSDocumentController sharedDocumentController] recentDocumentURLs]` to rebuild a list of recently opened items. This has been working well for a while now, but I recently got a report that it hangs a user's system:

`11  -[NSDocumentController(NSPrivate) _recentDocumentURLsForKey:] + 271 (AppKit + 5903428) [0x7fff92ae5444] 1-11
  11  -[__NSOperationInternal _waitUntilFinished:] + 131 (Foundation + 1060402) [0x7fff86a1ee32] 1-11
    11  __psynch_cvwait + 10 (libsystem_kernel.dylib + 94046) [0x7fff8dec6f5e] 1-11
     *11  psynch_cvcontinue + 0 (pthread + 30281) [0xffffff7f80e8d649] 1-11`

For the user reporting the bug, this started occurring after an upgrade to El Capitan - he routinely loads files from network shares, so I guess the system is blocking the call trying to locate the files. Looking around, it seems to be an issue that's been around for a while: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/317137-thread-deadlock.html and http://ticket.macromates.com/show?ticket_id=F3058D68.

The problem is, while several applications report that the issue is fixed, I haven't been able to track down the actual fix. What would be a suitable way to fix this? Is offloading it to a background thread the only suitable solution, or is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I worked around this by calling `recentDocumentURLs` in a separate thread, at app startup. Once the list is available, I place the URLs into an `NSMutableArray`, and from that point on update both `NSDocumentController` and the `NSMutableArray`.

To replicate the behavior of `NSDocumentController` using the array (keep only the unique URLs), I remove all URLs matching the new URL, then insert the new one at position 0.